# According to Jehovah's Witnesses, are the "overlapping generations" only the Witnesses or are they all the people of the current/last days?

Tags: terminology, eschatology, jehovahs-witnesses

As I understand Jehovah's Witnesses' eschatology, the "generation" Jesus referred to in Matthew 24:34 and parallels in Mark 13:30 and Luke 21:32 refers to all of the generations that saw the "tipping" of the New Jerusalem in Heaven in the direction of the planet (1914) and forward until "Armageddon occurs". Does that mean that "this generation" refers to all men living since 1914 until the end of the world or only the Jehovah's Witnesses? IE: Am I a part of the Jehovah's Witnesses' "overlapping generations" that will not pass from the scene until all the things in Matthew 24 take place, even though I'm not a Jehovah's Witness?

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/44353/23657.  Closely related

Comment: Thank you Kris, that answers my question. I guess I should move to close my question as a duplicate, even though my question is more specific. I guess my question isn't a complete duplicate but ironically, "overlapping"!  :)

Comment: You are welcome. I would leave it open there is a lot of other information available on jw.org that others may wish to answer your specific question with.

Comment: Yes, Kevin, it does. Thanks. If you would like to see this closed as a duplicate, please click the "close" button below the question. Thanks.